# Adding html tags inside title attribute of anchor tag

Tags: html

I have a image tag inside an  tag having title with html tags.

```
<a href="img_url" title="test #hashtag&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href='some_url'&gt;More...&lt;/a&gt;">
   <img src="img_url" alt="" title="" border="0" align="center">
</a>
```

but while displaying the tag it displays with the tags.
Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

What I am trying to accomplish here to render the title tag like plain html and not showing the tags. 
This is used in image library where I am using a jQuery plugin swipe-box which uses the title attribute of the  tag to display as a caption So like yahoo gallery I want to link the image to the main article.
Any ideas?

Comment: And its significance ??

Comment: There is no straight forward way to do this. If you really need to show HTML as title, you have to opt for jQuery tooltip plugins which support HTML. One such example is Tooltipster. You can see it here, http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#demos

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS Updated my question. I Don't want to use tooltip. just the default title attr. But the link you have given is awesome. will definitely use it in future projects

Comment: Are you asking how to put an `a` element inside a `title` element? What would you expect it to do? (It’s not possible. I’m asking what you expect it to do, because that might help to see what the original problem is.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela As I mentioned in question I am using jQuery swipe-box  plugin. So in that plugin whatever we want as a caption we should put it in the title of <a> tag Something like this: 
`<a href="img_url" title="test #hashtag&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href='some_url'&gt;More...&lt;/a&gt;">
   <img src="img_url" alt="" title="" border="0" align="center">
</a>`
Now when I open the picture the html is rendered fine. But the problem is when I hover the mouse on the image(before opening it in popup) it shows the tags and not the rendered html. Let me know if anything is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are using a plugin that reads the `title` attribute of an `a` element and constructs a presentation where that value is used as a visible title for an image. And you want that value to contain an `a` element, but you don’t want the markup to appear when the user mouses over the image

This is a feature of the plugin you are using. Modify it, or find a different plugin that suits your needs. If the visible title may need to contain HTML markup, a different approach is needed (unless you want the markup to be shown on mouseover). For example, you could make the plugin use `data-title` (perhaps falling back to `title` if `data-title` is not present.

The `title` attribute value is by definition just text (except that character references are interpreted), and this is how browsers treat it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to render the contents of the title tag as HTML. That is not supported.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? If you want a tooltip containing HTML to show up, I would put your HTML into a hidden div and have your div show up above the cursor or link on hover.

Comment: He wants to know how to get the html tag STORED, in the title attribute, in such a way that any script using it as-is as "innerHTML" can understand it as html, not literal text.