# How to store span in php variable then used as it tooltip text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tried to use tooltip for showing the value of span (which is span value to check user availability), so i store span value in php variable on echo it on tooltip tittle but not working.

here's my code

for example label nm_usr is the right tooltip and label log_usr is the variable i tried to echo it

```
    <tr>
        <td><label for="nm_usr">Nama</label></td>
        <td><input name="nm_usr" type="text" class="required" minlength="6" id="nm_usr" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" tittle="Masukkan nama lengkap anda" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="log_usr">Username</label></td>
        <?php
            $tittle = "<span id="usercheck" style="padding-left:10px; ; vertical-align: middle;"></span>";
        ?>
        <td><input name="log_usr" type="text" class="required" minlength="6" id="log_usr" onblur="checkUserName(this.value)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" tittle="<?php echo $tittle;?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Look at the highlighting, you have a fatal error. `"<span id="` You can't use the same quote types unescaped.

Comment: with double " i cant store that span i already aware that, but how to store fully functional span inside php variable ? or any other way to do it ?

Comment: You could encode it, not sure if it would process as expected then though.

Comment: `tittle=` ... should that be `title=`

Comment: @JaromandaX yep i recheck again and got repair it thx :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding html tags inside title attribute of anchor tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903419/adding-html-tags-inside-title-attribute-of-anchor-tag)

Comment: @chris85 and this is why i got blank tooltip but behind that tooltip i got my value on span, any idea to repair it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The attribute that you are looking for is title (not tittle).

(2) You should not put HTML inside the title attribute; it is invalid markup/will not validate.

(3) Your PHP code contains a syntax error:

```
$tittle = "<span id="usercheck" style="padding-left:10px; vertical-align: middle;"></span>";
```

Should be replaced with:

```
$tittle = '<span id="usercheck" style="padding-left:10px; ; vertical-align: middle;"></span>';
```

If you do wish to have HTML inside tooltips, I would suggest checking out jQuery UI's tooltips feature:

https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/